# Is $A$ an ideal of the ring $R$? Yes/No

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given $A= \{(2a,2b)| a,b \in\mathbb{Z}\} $   and $R=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{ Z}$

Is  $A$  an ideal of the ring $R$? Yes/No

**My attempt** : I think **No**

let $a=(2,2) \in A$ and  $r=(2,0) \in R$

then $ar=(2,0)(2,2)=(4,0) \notin A$

Therefore $A$ is not an ideal of  $R$

Is it true ?

Comment: $(4,0)\in A$, though.

Comment: Why do you think that $(4,0) \notin A\ $? Choose $a = 2$ and $b = 0.$ Then what is $(2a,2b)\ $? BTW $A$ is indeed an ideal of $R.$ Because for any $(m,n) \in R$ we have $$(m,n) \cdot (2a,2b) = (2(am), 2 (bn)).$$

Comment: oh  ! i get it now @AntonioClaire  thanks you  for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check $(A,+)$ is an additive subgroup. It suffices that $0\in A$ and $A$ is closed w.r.t taking the opposite element. Then for every $(r,s)\in R$ and $(2a,2b)\in A$
$$ (r,s)(2a,2b) = (2ar,2as) \in A $$
so $A$ is an ideal due to commutativity.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already clarifies your doubt. Here's something more. In general, the following is true:

If $A$ and $B$ are rings (commutative with $1$), then we have the following equality:

$$\{\text{ideals of }A \times B\} = \{I \times J : I \text{ is an ideal of } A,\ J \text{ is an ideal of } B\}.$$

That is, an ideal of $A \times B$ is *precisely* of the form $I \times J$ for ideals $I \subset A$ and $J \subset B$.

---

In your case, the set $A$ is $2\Bbb Z \times 2 \Bbb Z$ and thus, it is an ideal.

---

*Proof of the result.* It is easy to show that each set of the form $I \times J$ is an ideal. Indeed, it follows quite directly from the closure axioms of $I$ and $J$ being ideals.

The converse is a little bit trickier. Given an ideal $K \subset A \times B$, define the sets
\begin{align}
I := \{a \in A : (a, 0) \in K\}, \\
J := \{b \in B : (0, b) \in K\}.
\end{align}
Since $K$ is an ideal, it follows that $I$ and $J$ are also ideals. We claim that $K = I \times J$. This is a good exercise to do. Make use of the fact that our rings have $1$ and thus, we can write
\begin{align}
(a, b) &= (a, 0) \cdot (1, 0) + (0, b) \cdot (0, 1) \\
(a, 0) &= (a, b) \cdot (1, 0).
\end{align}

---

Note that the above is actually quite a nice result. For example, we don't have its analogue in groups. It is not true that subgroups of $G_1 \times G_2$ are of the form $H_1 \times H_2$ for $H_1 \leq G_1$ and $H_2 \leq G_2$.